# Update the range in an array

Tags: algorithm

Given an array of length N.I need to perform certain operations on this array, these operations are of two types:

```
Update a range [x...y]: In which we must divide each number in the given range [x...y] by K.(This division is integer division)

Query a range [x...y]: In which we must output the sum of all the numbers presently in range [x...y].
```

Example : Let say we have N=5 ,K=2 and array is {1,1,1,1,5} .let we have Q(=5) queries as follow :

2 1 5

1 1 2

2 1 5

1 5 5

2 1 5

Then in this Output will be  :

9

7

4

Now I know to solve it for smaller number of queries but how to do it if Q and N are large.

Comment: I'm confused. If there are five queries, why are there only three lines of output? Why do all of the queries have three numbers if there are only two parameters `x` and `y`? Or do you mean you have five operations? If so, how do you distinguish between updates and queries?

Comment: @Kevin Update symbolised by "1" and queries by "2"

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your question precisely.But I understand about querying...

->When you are running multiple queries on inputs like these

For Example:
If you have 1st query in range [2000,10000] and second one in range [2000,4000]
you end up adding these numbers multiple times,which is bad.

->Try using the concept of cumulative frequencies.

Ex:

```
1. Compute the cumulative sum for all indexes [0...n-1] in Array.

2. Now, When you need sum for a certain query [x...y] then just do
   Array[y]-Array[x-1].....which would be direct result.

3. Believe me this would save you lot of computation.

4. This concept is similar to Dynamic Programming(try Googling it!!)
```

Comment: i know about querying,main problem is about updating the value in which i need to divide each value in a range of elements by K.

Comment: I think segment tree implementation will work,But i am not getting how to implement it